# How to skip optional windows updates in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, updates

I found a script to download windows updates that I've been tweaking to fit my needs. It seems to work fine except I can't figure out how to remove the optional updates before downloading. I've found that the "Critical", "Important", and "Moderate" updates will have a MsrcSeverity value of one of those 3 words, where optional will be blank. How do I remove the updates with no msrcseverity value from the list before downloading??

Here's the whole code...

```
$global:scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$global:dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
$global:logfile = "$dir\updatelog.txt"

write-host " Searching for updates..."
$session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$searcher = $session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$result = $searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")

if ($result.Updates.Count -eq 0) {
     Write-Host "No updates to install"
}

else {

    $result.Updates | Select Title
    $result.Title >> $logfile

}

$downloads = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl

foreach ($update in $result){

    $downloads.Add($update)

}

$count = $result.Updates.Count

write-host ""
write-host "There are $($count) updates available."
write-host ""

read-host "Press Enter to download\install updates"

$downloader = $session.CreateUpdateDownLoader()
$downloader.Updates = $downloads
$downloader.Download()

$installs = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
foreach ($update in $result.Updates){
     if ($update.IsDownloaded){
           $installs.Add($update)
     }
}

$installer = $session.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$installer.Updates = $installs
$installresult = $installer.Install()
$installresult
```

I have the "read-host" in there right now to stop it from downloading until I get this figured out. I've tried putting an extra pipe in `$result.updates | Select Title | where {$result.Updates.MsrcSeverity -ne $null}`, I've also tried that with just `$result.MsrcSeverity` and no go. I've tried the "where" pipe in a couple different places. I've also tried making an If statement in a couple places that says if the MsrcSeverity doesn't equal null then add it to the list. I've also tried adding onto the `$searcher.Search(` line with an `and MsrcSeverity = 'Important'")` just to test and that didn't do anything.

So far it still lists all the updates whether or not there's something in the MsrcSeverity column. Am I looking in the wrong place? It's the only thing I can see that tells the difference between an Important update and an Optional.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Search criterias are documented at [IUpdateSearcher::Search method](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/windows/desktop/api/wuapi/nf-wuapi-iupdatesearcher-search)

The `BrowseOnly=0` unfortunately doesn't exclude Optional updates as seen in Windows Update program. But `AutoSelectOnWebSites=1` does.

> - "BrowseOnly=1" finds updates that are considered optional.
> - "BrowseOnly=0" finds updates that are not considered optional.
> - "AutoSelectOnWebSites=1" finds updates that are flagged to be automatically selected by Windows Update.
> - "AutoSelectOnWebSites=0" finds updates that are not flagged for Automatic Updates.

```
$session1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
$searcher = $session1.CreateUpdateSearcher()
#Do not search for optional updates and exclude hidden
$result = $searcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 AND AutoSelectOnWebSites=1 AND IsHidden=0")
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for all the help, everyone. I got so many helpful suggestions I didn't know where to begin...

I got it figured out, thanks.

Comment: Can you share your solution? I'm working on a similar problem

Comment: Downvoting because this is not an answer to the question. If one of the answers is correct, accept it. If you found your own solution, post that as the answer and accept it.